# Ruby: Creating a class method that all classes can use

Tags: ruby, class, methods, shared

I am trying to create a method that can be called by any class, similar to how .is_a? can be called by any class. How can one go about this?

I have tried using alias_method and Class.send(method) to achieve my result, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Object class and write your method there.

```
class Object 
  def your_method
  end
end
```

Now any class object can access this method.